# FastAPI gunicon uvicorn access_log format customization

Tags: gunicorn, fastapi

We are using the https://github.com/tiangolo/uvicorn-gunicorn-fastapi-docker FastAPI and were able to customize our logging with a gunicorn logging file.

However, we are not able to change the details of the %(message)s attribute as defined in the documentation access log - https://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/settings.html#accesslog.

We receive an error postet below, that the keys are unknown.
A similar question has been asked before and received many upvotes.
[gunicorn log-config access_log_format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56538791/gunicorn-log-config-access-log-format)

What are we doing wrong?

```
#start.sh
# Start Gunicorn
exec gunicorn -k uvicorn.workers.UvicornWorker -c "$GUNICORN_CONF" "$APP_MODULE" --log-config "/logging.conf"
```

```
[loggers]
keys=root, gunicorn.error, gunicorn.access,uvicorn.error,uvicorn.access

[handlers]
keys=console, error_file, access_file, access_filegunicorn

[formatters]
keys=generic, access, accessgunicorn

[logger_root]
level=INFO
handlers=console
propagate=1

[logger_gunicorn.error]
level=INFO
handlers=error_file
propagate=0
qualname=gunicorn.error

[logger_gunicorn.access]
level=INFO
handlers=access_filegunicorn
propagate=0
qualname=gunicorn.access

[logger_uvicorn.error]
level=INFO
handlers=error_file
propagate=0
qualname=uvicorn.error

[logger_uvicorn.access]
level=INFO
handlers=access_file
propagate=0
qualname=uvicorn.access

[handler_console]
class=StreamHandler
formatter=generic
args=(sys.stdout, )

[handler_error_file]
class=StreamHandler
formatter=generic
args=(sys.stdout, )

[handler_access_file]
class=StreamHandler
formatter=access
args=(sys.stdout, )

[handler_access_filegunicorn]
class=StreamHandler
formatter=accessgunicorn
args=(sys.stdout, )

[formatter_generic]
format=[%(levelname)s]: %(message)s
datefmt=%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S
class=logging.Formatter

[formatter_access]
format=[%(levelname)s]: %(message)s
datefmt=%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S
class=logging.Formatter

[formatter_accessgunicorn]
format=[%(levelname)s]: '{"remote_ip":"%(h)s","session_id":"%({X-Session-Id}i)s","status":"%(s)s","request_method":"%(m)s","request_path":"%(U)s","request_querystring":"%(q)s","request_timetaken":"%(D)s","response_length":"%(B)s", "remote_addr": "%(h)s"}'
datefmt=%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S
class=logging.Formatter
```

```
Message: '%s - "%s %s HTTP/%s" %d'
Arguments: ('213.3.14.24:53374', 'GET', '/v1/docs', '1.1', 200)
--- Logging error ---
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/logging/__init__.py", line 1025, in emit
    msg = self.format(record)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/logging/__init__.py", line 869, in format
    return fmt.format(record)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/logging/__init__.py", line 611, in format
    s = self.formatMessage(record)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/logging/__init__.py", line 580, in formatMessage
    return self._style.format(record)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/logging/__init__.py", line 422, in format
    return self._fmt % record.__dict__
KeyError: 'h'
Call stack:
  File "/usr/local/bin/gunicorn", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(run())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 58, in run
    WSGIApplication("%(prog)s [OPTIONS] [APP_MODULE]").run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 228, in run
    super().run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 72, in run
    Arbiter(self).run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 202, in run
    self.manage_workers()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 545, in manage_workers
    self.spawn_workers()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 616, in spawn_workers
    self.spawn_worker()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 583, in spawn_worker
    worker.init_process()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/uvicorn/workers.py", line 61, in init_process
    super(UvicornWorker, self).init_process()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 140, in init_process
    self.run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/uvicorn/workers.py", line 70, in run
    loop.run_until_complete(server.serve(sockets=self.sockets))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/uvicorn/protocols/http/httptools_impl.py", line 385, in run_asgi
    result = await app(self.scope, self.receive, self.send)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/uvicorn/middleware/proxy_headers.py", line 45, in __call__
    return await self.app(scope, receive, send)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/fastapi/applications.py", line 171, in __call__
    await super().__call__(scope, receive, send)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/starlette/applications.py", line 102, in __call__
    await self.middleware_stack(scope, receive, send)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/starlette/middleware/errors.py", line 159, in __call__
    await self.app(scope, receive, _send)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/starlette/middleware/cors.py", line 78, in __call__
    await self.app(scope, receive, send)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/starlette/exceptions.py", line 71, in __call__
    await self.app(scope, receive, sender)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/starlette/routing.py", line 550, in __call__
    await route.handle(scope, receive, send)
```

Comment: Can you explain what extra data you are trying to log?

Comment: its this line: format=[%(levelname)s]: '{"remote_ip":"%(h)s","session_id":"%({X-Session-Id}i)s","status":"%(s)s","request_method":"%(m)s","request_path":"%(U)s","request_querystring":"%(q)s","request_timetaken":"%(D)s","response_length":"%(B)s", "remote_addr": "%(h)s"}'   , i think its self-explanatory and follows the gunicorn doucmentation

Comment: @ArakkalAbu It seems that the https://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/settings.html#access-log-format setting does not work when set via --access-logformat STRING, so I tried to define it in a logging config file. However there are a lot of wrappers involved - see here https://github.com/aio-libs/aiohttp/issues/705

Comment: seems like gunicorn issue

Comment: @ArakkalAbu yes i also believe it is some kind of a bug. I even tried adding "access_log_format = ..." to the log config but this didnt help

Comment: Have you tried common python logger formats? instead of `gunicorn`'s? Something like `'%(asctime)s - %(message)s'` ?

Comment: Did this approach end up working out?

Comment: @user670186 the `gunicorn.access` logger is only used by the Gunicorn worker classes. Uvicorn workers don't use it at all, instead they use `uvicorn.access`. So any Gunicorn config for access logging will have no effect by default. You need to configure the `uvicorn.access` logger instead, e.g. in one of the Gunicorn server hooks that runs in the worker upon startup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Our solution was a customer logger written in python that is referenced in a logging.conf file

logging.conf

```
[loggers]
keys=root, gunicorn.error, gunicorn.access,uvicorn.error,uvicorn.access

[handlers]
keys=console, error_file, access_file, accesscustom

[formatters]
keys=generic, access, AccessFormatter

[logger_root]
level=INFO
handlers=console
propagate=1

[logger_gunicorn.error]
level=INFO
handlers=error_file
propagate=0
qualname=gunicorn.error

[logger_gunicorn.access]
level=INFO
handlers=accesscustom
propagate=0
qualname=gunicorn.access

[logger_uvicorn.error]
level=INFO
handlers=error_file
propagate=0
qualname=uvicorn.error

[logger_uvicorn.access]
level=INFO
handlers=accesscustom
propagate=0
qualname=uvicorn.access

[handler_console]
class=StreamHandler
formatter=generic
args=(sys.stdout, )

[handler_error_file]
class=StreamHandler
formatter=generic
args=(sys.stdout, )

[handler_access_file]
class=StreamHandler
formatter=access
args=(sys.stdout, )

[handler_accesscustom]
class=StreamHandler
formatter=AccessFormatter
args=(sys.stdout, )

[formatter_generic]
format=%(levelname)s: %(message)s
datefmt=%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S
class=uvicorn.logging.DefaultFormatter

[formatter_access]
format=%(levelname)s: %(message)s
datefmt=%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S
class=customlogger.CustomFormatter

[formatter_AccessFormatter]
format={"event":"access_log","ip":"%(h)s","status":"%(s)s","method":"%(m)s","path":"%(U)s","referer":"%(f)s","x_session_id":"%(x-session-id)s","x_google_id":"%(x-google-id)s","x_server_time":"%(x-server-time)s","agent":"%(a)s"}
datefmt=%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S
class=customlogger.CustomFormatter
```

customlogger.py

```py
import base64
import binascii
import http
import logging
import os
import sys
import time
from copy import copy
from datetime import datetime
from pprint import pprint
import click

TRACE_LOG_LEVEL = 5


class ColourizedFormatter(logging.Formatter):
    """
    A custom log formatter class that:
    * Outputs the LOG_LEVEL with an appropriate color.
    * If a log call includes an `extras={"color_message": ...}` it will be used
      for formatting the output, instead of the plain text message.
    """

    level_name_colors = {
        TRACE_LOG_LEVEL: lambda level_name: click.style(str(level_name), fg="blue"),
        logging.DEBUG: lambda level_name: click.style(str(level_name), fg="cyan"),
        logging.INFO: lambda level_name: click.style(str(level_name), fg="green"),
        logging.WARNING: lambda level_name: click.style(str(level_name), fg="yellow"),
        logging.ERROR: lambda level_name: click.style(str(level_name), fg="red"),
        logging.CRITICAL: lambda level_name: click.style(
            str(level_name), fg="bright_red"
        ),
    }

    def __init__(self, fmt=None, datefmt=None, style="%", use_colors=None):
        if use_colors in (True, False):
            self.use_colors = use_colors
        else:
            self.use_colors = sys.stdout.isatty()
        super().__init__(fmt=fmt, datefmt=datefmt, style=style)

    def color_level_name(self, level_name, level_no):
        default = lambda level_name: str(level_name)
        func = self.level_name_colors.get(level_no, default)
        return func(level_name)

    def should_use_colors(self):
        return True

    def formatMessage(self, record):
        recordcopy = copy(record)
        levelname = recordcopy.levelname
        seperator = " " * (8 - len(recordcopy.levelname))
        if self.use_colors:
            levelname = self.color_level_name(levelname, recordcopy.levelno)
            if "color_message" in recordcopy.__dict__:
                recordcopy.msg = recordcopy.__dict__["color_message"]
                recordcopy.__dict__["message"] = recordcopy.getMessage()
        recordcopy.__dict__["levelprefix"] = levelname + ":" + seperator
        return super().formatMessage(recordcopy)


class DefaultFormatter(ColourizedFormatter):
    def should_use_colors(self):
        return sys.stderr.isatty()


class AccessFormatter(ColourizedFormatter):
    status_code_colours = {
        1: lambda code: click.style(str(code), fg="bright_white"),
        2: lambda code: click.style(str(code), fg="green"),
        3: lambda code: click.style(str(code), fg="yellow"),
        4: lambda code: click.style(str(code), fg="red"),
        5: lambda code: click.style(str(code), fg="bright_red"),
    }

    def get_client_addr(self, scope):
        client = scope.get("client")
        if not client:
            return ""
        return "%s:%d" % (client[0], client[1])

    def get_path(self, scope):
        return scope.get("root_path", "") + scope["path"]

    def get_full_path(self, scope):
        path = scope.get("root_path", "") + scope["path"]
        query_string = scope.get("query_string", b"").decode("ascii")
        if query_string:
            return path + "?" + query_string
        return path

    def get_status_code(self, record):
        status_code = record.__dict__["status_code"]
        try:
            status_phrase = http.HTTPStatus(status_code).phrase
        except ValueError:
            status_phrase = ""
        status_and_phrase = "%s %s" % (status_code, status_phrase)

        if self.use_colors:
            default = lambda code: status_and_phrase
            func = self.status_code_colours.get(status_code // 100, default)
            return func(status_and_phrase)
        return status_and_phrase

    def formatMessage(self, record):
        recordcopy = copy(record)
        scope = recordcopy.__dict__["scope"]
        method = scope["method"]
        path = self.get_path(scope)
        full_path = self.get_full_path(scope)
        client_addr = self.get_client_addr(scope)
        status_code = self.get_status_code(recordcopy)
        http_version = scope["http_version"]
        request_line = "%s %s HTTP/%s" % (method, full_path, http_version)
        if self.use_colors:
            request_line = click.style(request_line, bold=True)
        recordcopy.__dict__.update(
            {
                "method": method,
                "path": path,
                "full_path": full_path,
                "client_addr": client_addr,
                "request_line": request_line,
                "status_code": status_code,
                "http_version": http_version,
            }
        )
        return super().formatMessage(recordcopy)


class SafeAtoms(dict):

    def __init__(self, atoms):
        dict.__init__(self)
        for key, value in atoms.items():
            if isinstance(value, str):
                self[key] = value.replace('"', '\\"')
            else:
                self[key] = value

    def __getitem__(self, k):
        if k.startswith("{"):
            kl = k.lower()
            if kl in self:
                return super().__getitem__(kl)
            else:
                return "-"
        if k in self:
            return super().__getitem__(k)
        else:
            return '-'


class CustomFormatter(AccessFormatter):
    atoms_wrapper_class = SafeAtoms

    def now(self):
        """ return date in Apache Common Log Format """
        return time.strftime('[%d/%b/%Y:%H:%M:%S %z]')

    def _get_user(self, environ):
        user = None
        http_auth = environ.get("HTTP_AUTHORIZATION")
        if http_auth and http_auth.lower().startswith('basic'):
            auth = http_auth.split(" ", 1)
            if len(auth) == 2:
                try:
                    # b64decode doesn't accept unicode in Python < 3.3
                    # so we need to convert it to a byte string
                    auth = base64.b64decode(auth[1].strip().encode('utf-8'))
                    # b64decode returns a byte string
                    auth = auth.decode('utf-8')
                    auth = auth.split(":", 1)
                except (TypeError, binascii.Error, UnicodeDecodeError) as exc:
                    self.debug("Couldn't get username: %s", exc)
                    return user
                if len(auth) == 2:
                    user = auth[0]
        return user

    def atoms(self, environ, request_time, scope, statuscode, created):
        headers = dict(scope.get('headers',[('-','-')]))
        response_headers = dict(scope.get('response_headers',[('-','-')]))
        atoms = {
            'h': scope.get("client", ('-', ''))[0],
            'l': '-',
            's': statuscode,
            'u': self._get_user(environ) or '-',
            't': created,
            'm': str(scope.get("method", "-")),
            'U': scope.get("path", "-"),
            'q': scope.get("query_string", "-").decode("utf-8"),
            'H': str(scope.get("type", "-")),
            'f': headers.get(b"referer", b"-").decode("utf-8"),
            'a': headers.get(b"user-agent", b"-").decode("utf-8"),
            'x-session-id': headers.get(b"x-session-id", b"-").decode("utf-8"),
            'x-google-id': headers.get(b"x-google-id", b"-").decode("utf-8"),  
            'x-server-time': response_headers.get(b"x-server-time", b"").decode("utf-8"),   
            'p': "<%s>" % os.getpid()
        }

        return atoms

    def formatMessage(self, record):
        recordcopy = copy(record)
        scope = recordcopy.__dict__["scope"]
        #pprint(vars(recordcopy))
        safe_atoms = self.atoms_wrapper_class(
            self.atoms(os.environ, datetime.now(), scope, recordcopy.status_code, recordcopy.created)
        )
        recordcopy.__dict__.update(safe_atoms)

        # pprint(vars(os.environ))
        return super().formatMessage(recordcopy)
```

Comment: Are you also using a middleware so you can give the scope?

Answer (score 8):

I found very useful information here https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/issues/1508

I needed to add the request datetime , and the solution that I implemented was:

```py
@app.on_event("startup")
async def startup_event():
    logger = logging.getLogger("uvicorn.access")
    console_formatter = uvicorn.logging.ColourizedFormatter(
        "{asctime} {levelprefix} : {message}",
        style="{", use_colors=True)
    logger.handlers[0].setFormatter(console_formatter)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    uvicorn.run(app, host="0.0.0.0", port=8000)
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm also using the FastAPI - Uvicorn - Gunicorn stack.

To modify the format of the uvicorn logging, I first inspected its current configuration :

```py
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> import uvicorn.config
>>> pprint(uvicorn.config.LOGGING_CONFIG)

{'disable_existing_loggers': False,
 'formatters': {'access': {'()': 'uvicorn.logging.AccessFormatter',
                           'fmt': '%(levelprefix)s %(client_addr)s - '
                                  '"%(request_line)s" %(status_code)s'},
                'default': {'()': 'uvicorn.logging.DefaultFormatter',
                            'fmt': '%(levelprefix)s %(message)s',
                            'use_colors': None}},
 'handlers': {'access': {'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
                         'formatter': 'access',
                         'stream': 'ext://sys.stdout'},
              'default': {'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
                          'formatter': 'default',
                          'stream': 'ext://sys.stderr'}},
 'loggers': {'uvicorn': {'handlers': ['default'], 'level': 'INFO'},
             'uvicorn.access': {'handlers': ['access'],
                                'level': 'INFO',
                                'propagate': False},
             'uvicorn.error': {'level': 'INFO'}},
 'version': 1}
```

And I created my own logging configuration based on the default configuration of uvicorn. I added the date/time of the log, and my own custom logger :

```py
import logging

LOGGER_NAME = "myapp"

log_config = {
    "version": 1,
    "disable_existing_loggers": False,
    "formatters": {
        'access': {
            '()': 'uvicorn.logging.AccessFormatter',
            'fmt': '%(levelprefix)s %(asctime)s - %(client_addr)s - "%(request_line)s" %(status_code)s',
            "datefmt": "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S",
            "use_colors": True
        },
        "default": {
            "()": "uvicorn.logging.DefaultFormatter",
            "fmt": "%(levelprefix)s %(asctime)s - %(message)s",
            "datefmt": "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S",
            "use_colors": True
        },
    },
    "handlers": {
        'access': {
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
            'formatter': 'access',
            'stream': 'ext://sys.stdout'
        },
        "default": {
            "formatter": "default",
            "class": "logging.StreamHandler",
            "stream": "ext://sys.stderr",
        },
    },
    "loggers": {
        LOGGER_NAME: {
            "handlers": ["default"],
            "level": "DEBUG",
            "propagate": False
        },
        "uvicorn": {
            "handlers": ["default"],
            "level": "DEBUG",
            "propagate": True
        },
        'uvicorn.access': {
            'handlers': ['access'],
            'level': 'INFO',
            'propagate': False
        },
        'uvicorn.error': {
            'level': 'INFO',
            'propagate': False
        }
    },
}


def get_logger():
    return logging.getLogger(LOGGER_NAME)
```

Then in my `main.py` file, where  I defined `app = FastAPI(...)`, I configure the logging just after my imports lines with :

```py
logging.config.dictConfig(log_config)
```

And I do custom logging in my app by using the custom logger that I defined :

```py
logger = get_logger()
logger.info("Hello World!")
```